# How to search in json object in angular using a string?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

**Json**

```
{
  "rootData": {
    "test1": {
      "testData0": "Previous data",
      "testData1": "Earlier Data"
    },
    "test2": {
      "testData0": "Partial data",
      "testData1": "Services data"
    },
    "test3": {
      "testData0": "Regular data",
      "testData1": {
        "testData0": "Your package"
      }
}
}      
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import  *  as  configData  from  './myData.json';

getData(data: string){    
  console.log(configData.rootData.test1.testData0); //returns "Previous Data.
    
 return configData.rootData.{{data}}.testData0;
}
```

This getData method is being called in a loop passing a string with values of "test1" the first time "test2" the second time and "test3" the third time called.

I want to do something like this

```
return configData.rootData.{{data}}.testData0; //should return Previous data, then "partial data" if called again because test2 will be passed in data string.
```

I know this is not possible the way I am doing it because {{data}} is not defined in my json object.

The goal is to check for the object inside the object. The string data is returning values existing in the json object. I want to use that data to dynamically search in the json file and pull the values.

I know my attempt is not valid. I would like to know if there is an alternative to make this work as I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value with the `key` in Object, you can use `Object[key]` (here, `key` is variable name) and this will return the value of the selected key.

```
return configData.rootData[data]?.testData0; // Javascript case
```

So instead of using `{{ }}`, replace it with square brackets and you will get the result.

And on the above code, `rootData[data]?.testData0` has same meaning as `rootData[data] ? rootData[data].testData0 : undefined` so this will be needed for validation check. (unexpected `data` value input)

On Typescript,

```
if (data in configData.rootData && "testData0" in configData.rootData[data]) {
  return configData.rootData[data].testData0;
} else {
  return undefined;
}
```

```js
const input = {
  "rootData": {
    "test1": {
      "testData0": "Previous data",
      "testData1": "Earlier Data"
    },
    "test2": {
      "testData0": "Partial data",
      "testData1": "Services data"
    },
    "test3": {
      "testData0": "Regular data",
      "testData1": {
        "testData0": "Your package"
      }
    }
  }
};

let data = 'test1';
console.log(input.rootData[data]?.testData0);

data = 'test2';
console.log(input.rootData[data]?.testData0);

data = 'test3';
console.log(input.rootData[data]?.testData0);

data = 'test4';
console.log(input.rootData[data]?.testData0);

data = 'test5';
if (data in input.rootData) {
  console.log('Existed', input.rootData[data].testData0);
} else {
  console.log('Not Existed');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Derek, QQ regarding rootData[data]?. does this handle like null/undefined values? ex: will it ignore and skip or will it throw an error

Comment: As you see the last example, for data input `test4`, it returns `undefined` because the value is not existed.

Comment: I am getting the following error with the logic you provided.
 error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(308,42): error TS1005: ':' expected.

Comment: test(data: string){  
console.log(configData.rootData[data]?.testData0);
}

Comment: Oh, I forgot it's using the typescript, I have updated my answer adding the typescript case.

Comment: Hey Derek, what if testData0 is undefined?

Comment: if `testData0` is undefined, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: I thought the ? was to check if data was null/undefined. and if data has value it will check for data.testData0 (and if this is undefined) I am getting an undefined error. for testData0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223521/discussion-between-derek-w-and-jesse).

Answer (score 0):

I use [ng2-search-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter).

By directive

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of configData | filter:searchText">
  <td>{{testData0}}</td>
  <td>{{testData1}}</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Or programmatically

```
let configDataFiltered = new Ng2SearchPipe().transform(this.configData, searchText);
```

Practical example: https://angular-search-filter.stackblitz.io